# $2^x=4.019$, solve for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

If I know that $2^b= 4.019$, how do I solve for $b$? I'm sure it's an algebraic method, but not knowing the term makes it impossible to search for.

Comment: Do you know what a logarithm is?

Comment: You just need the logarithm to solve this : $\large b=\frac{\ln(4.019)}{\ln(2)}=2.0068\cdots $

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition:
$$b^x=y \implies x=\log_b(y)$$
Where $\log_b(y)$ is the [logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) to a base $b$.

---

Note that $\log_b(y)$ can also be written as:
$$\log_b(y)=\frac{\log_c(y)}{\log_c(b)}$$
Where $c$ is any positive base not equal to $1$. You can choose any value of $c$, one may also choose base $e$ to obtain:
$$\log_b(y)=\frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(b)}$$

---

Therefore, to answer your question:
$$2^x=4.019 \implies x=\log_2(4.019)=\frac{\log_c(4.019)}{\log_c(2)}=\frac{\ln(4.019)}{\ln(2)}\approx 2.00684$$